# swallowing assertexceptions in nunit

Tags: nunit

Running the code below  both in VSCode and in Visual Studio is reported as failed although the exception is swallowed :(

Why it works this way? How can I make NUnit forget about the thrown exception?

```cs
        [Test]
        public void TestExceptionReporting() {
            try {
                Assert.False(true);
            } catch(AssertionException e) {
                Log.Debug($">>> {e.ToString()}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it work that way...

Because NUnit processes and records the error internally before you can catch the exception. The exception is propogated after processing solely as a way to terminte the test. For that reason, it is no longer a good idea to catch NUnit's own exceptions in a test.

How can you make NUnit forget about the test failure?

This is an xy question. Please explain why you want NUnit to notice a failure and  then forget it. There are lots of ways to make NUnit take note of a condition without failing, but to answer folks need to know what you are actually trying to do.

You could either edit this question (and I can edit my answer) or ask a new question about what you really want to do.

Comment: I am trying to use NUnit for system testing. This means that the test works asynchronously to the SUT. Hence, every operation may fail and needs to be retried several times just because the SUT is not yet in a ready state or updated state. For example, it may take some time until the screen gets populated or updated, buttons may be missing or disabled, data may not be loaded. This is true for assertions too. The test may expect some field to display Y but it is still X. This happens even with fastest application, like Windows calculator. So I am using a retry mechanism wrapping every operation

Comment: My current workaround is just not to use Assert.XXX at all. I found a method called IsSuccess and if it is false I am building an AssertionException myself initialized with a description of failure and throw it. Meanwhile it seems that it works ok.

Comment: The old-school way of doing this is to separate your system tests from your unit tests. Unit tests are expected to pass 100% of the time and any failure should break the build. Other kinds of tests that are not yet passing (Customer, System, etc.) go into a separate assembly and test run, which does __not__ break the build upon failure.